# SQL query for column threaded relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a simplified view of a table.  I apologize, but I could not save a picture of the table so I hope this is ok.

> c1`___`c2
>   1`____`a
>   1`____`b
>   2`____`a
>   2`____`b
>   2`____`c
>   2`____`d
>   3`____`e
>   3`____`a
>   4`____`z
>   5`____`d

The result is that due to the relationships of column C2, 
Group 1 would include, 1,2,3,5 (because they have overlapping c2 values basically stating a=b=c=d=e)
Group 2 would include 4

I have millions of rows with this kind of data and currently there is a cursor job that runs x number of times to build these groups.  I am able to visualize how this should work, but I have not been able to build a query that can pull out this relationship.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: This type of operation is fairly complex, likely requiring something like a temp table and a loop or recursive cte to generate all the groups.  Why do you want to condense your cursor job into a single query?

Comment: I was able to get all the groups filled out here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf29c/5.  Turning that into the group sets is even more complicated, but should be possible with another temp table and loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  There are 2 reasons for taking a different route. 1. it takes over an hour to run, 2. instead of a do while loop, we have created an x repeat chunk of cursor code.  Meaning, we have the 'cursor code' written 3 times and if we find a letter in more than one group, then we add another repeated chunk of the cursor code.  I think it would be more efficient to figure out a way to loop through the matching functionality until the matching has completed.  You have provided me with some additional ideas though.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on SQL Server 2012:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        t.c1,
        t.c2,
        tm.c1_min
    FROM
        Test t
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                c2,
                MIN(c1) AS c1_min
            FROM
                Test
            GROUP BY
                c2
        ) AS tm
    ON
        t.c2 = tm.c2
),
rt AS (
    SELECT
        c1_min,
        c1,
        1 AS cnt
    FROM
        t
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        rt.c1_min,
        t.c1,
        rt.cnt + 1 AS cnt
    FROM
        rt
    JOIN
        t
    ON
        rt.c1 = t.c1_min
    AND
        rt.c1 < t.c1
)
SELECT
    SUM(t.rst) OVER (ORDER BY t.ord ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS group_number,
    t.c1
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.c1,
            t.rst,
            t.ord
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    rt.c1,
                    CASE
                        WHEN rt.c1_min = MIN(rt.c1_min) OVER (ORDER BY rt.c1_min, rt.c1 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END AS rst,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rt.c1_min, rt.c1) AS ord,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rt.c1 ORDER BY rt.c1_min, rt.cnt) AS qfy
                FROM
                    rt
            ) AS t
        WHERE
            t.qfy = 1
    ) AS t;
```